# Angular + Firestore Autocomplete

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I have an autocomplete search bar on my website. It is built with Angular 7 and the information is coming from my Firestore database. Currently, the search bar is not filtering through the options when the user types. The onLoad() function should make one fetch into my `Schools` collection, and filter through that collection as the user types.

**Code for the search bar**

```
      <form>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 50vw; max-width: 400px;" appearance="outline">
          <input matInput placeholder="Search schools..." aria-label="School" [matAutocomplete]="auto" #schoolInput [(ngModel)]="searchModel" (keyup.enter)="searchButton(schoolInput.value)" name="inputField" id="searchInput">
          <mat-icon class="searchIcon" matSuffix style="color: #6336c6;" (click)="searchButton(schoolInput.value)">search</mat-icon>
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let school of schools | async" [value]="school.name">
              <span class="ui tiny header">{{ school.name }}</span>
              <span *ngIf="school.country == 'United States'; then withState else withoutState"></span>
              <ng-template #withState><small> {{school.city}}, {{school.state}}</small></ng-template>
              <ng-template #withoutState><small> {{school.city}}, {{school.country}}</small></ng-template>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngIf="user" (click)="openDialogAddSchool()" style="font-style: italic; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
              <button class="ui basic fluid violet button" style="margin-top:6px;"><i class="plus icon"></i>Add school</button>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
```

**TS Code so far**

```
fetchSchools(){

    this.schoolsCollection = this.afs.collection('Schools', ref => {
      return ref.orderBy('name');
    });

    this.schools = this.schoolsCollection.valueChanges();

    console.log('Retreived schools:');
    console.log(this.schools);

  }
```

**Response**
Retreived schools:

```
page-home.component.ts:308 Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show the TS code, also can you add a sample of the data you are getting from firebase as code in your question. That way this can be tested and debugged :)

Comment: I updated the post with the TS code where I'm fetching the collection, which I'm logging (3rd pic on bottom).

Comment: Thanks, but could you add a sample of the response as code, so that it can be copied and tested :) I'm not going to write the response long hand ;)

Comment: What do you mean? Should I interpolate the response into the HTML template?

Comment: no, you are showing the response in a picture... I would like to have it in a JSON format. So if you post your response as code in your question, it should look something like: `Schools: [..., ...]` That way I can **copy** your piece of data to an editor and test it.

Comment: Gotcha. I added the response as code above :)

Comment: That is not the JSON response, it's the observable value. Well, I'll see what I can do...

Comment: Do collections normally come back as full JSON responses? I'm logging Firestore Documents that do.

Comment: No, but you can subscribe to it and console log the value. But that is not needed anymore, I wrote some sample myself. But now I see you have a function on keyup.enter. How does that function look like? Remember when you post code that it is a [mcve], i.e can be tested in a playground.

Comment: oh wait, it's not a relevant piece of code, if it's enter key. Nevermind, sorry :D

Comment: Yeah, just checking for the enter key which triggers a route change based on the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a service, usually we use a service to handle http-calls and in this case firebase queries. So I would create the service, create a variable of `schools`, and either return an observable of it if it has value, or then return the result from the firebase query unless you want to always query the db, but that would become really expensive.

```ts
schools = [];

fetchSchools() {
  if (this.schools && this.schools.length) {
    return of(this.schools)
  } else {
    return this.afs.collection('Schools', ref => {
      return ref.orderBy('name')
    }).valueChanges().pipe(
        tap((schools) => this.schools = schools)
      );
  }
}
```

The component would subscribe to this and assign the data to an observable after the data has been filtered. I like to add a `debounceTime`:

```ts
filterSchools() {
  this.schoolsObs = this.myService.fetchSchools().pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    map((data) => this.performFilter(data))
  )
}
```

Then you can choose how the filtering is done... using `startsWith`, `includes` (??). Also choose the prop you want to filter by. My sample looks like this:

```ts
performFilter(schoolsObs) {
  return schoolsObs.filter((x) => {
    // filter by what prop you want
    return x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.searchModel.trim().toLowerCase())
  })
}
```

Then finally for the template, I would listen to `input` from the user:

```html
<input 
  matInput 
  [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
  (input)="filterSchools()" 
  [(ngModel)]="searchModel"
>
```

DEMO: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jd2dsu-4ctkm8?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)**

Comment: I noticed an issue: It's only filtering through the local `data` variable, not through the Firestore `schools` variable, even when I force it as the only condition in `fetchSchools()`. I added a third school to the website, 'Harvard University', but the autocomplete isn't seeing it.

Comment: If you are forcing it to always query the db, it should, since we are calling `valueChanges` `return this.afs.collection('Schools', ref => { return ref.orderBy('name').valueChanges();})` should always query the db in that case.

Comment: Oh, I was following the StackBlitz and I didn't see the `.valueChanges` here. I added it in but I'm getting two errors: imgur.com/a/muul94E

Comment: oh sorry, valueChanges was in wrong place, check now :)

Comment: Anyway, you need to think about some way to store the data locally, for at least x amount of time. Firebase charges for every read and write, and there will be a LOT of reads if the db is queried constantly. For production this would be a disaster. So you need to see how it fits your needs for future :) Am going offline now, so if there is something still with issue, I'll get back to you tomorrow :)

Comment: Wouldn't `ref.orderBy('name').limit(3)` charge only 3 db fetches per letter typed?

Comment: Rather than going to Firestore and fetching a collection every time a user enters another letter, is it possible to fetch the collection once when the page loads during onLoad() (into a variable), then just keep filtering through that variable every time the user types another letter?

Comment: The limit would help. To fetch once and then filter that variable sounds good to me. That is kind of the idea of my answer, except the variable is in the service. But you can move that assignment part to the component and store the data in a variable in the component instead.

Comment: I already have them in the same component. I made 2 changes: imgur.com/a/q3MMwT3 . I'm fetching the schools once in ngOnInit() (although it doesn't feel like it due to the latency) and filtering through that saved variable in filterSchools(). I think it's still fetching the DB every letter for some reason...

Comment: you can use `valueChanges().pipe(take(1))`. That only fetches the data once for sure. I also no noticed that my code was incomplete. I never assigned `this.schools` any data ****facepalm**** so I added a `tap` now, which would assign data to `this.schools` in my service code.

Comment: It feels a lot snappier now. I think it's cutting down on the the firestore calls. Here's what I have: imgur.com/a/kXFnUIG . I also pushed the update to the site: https://quizmenot.com

Comment: Hey, I'm curious how I can limit the number of schools that show up in the dropdown menu at any given time. Right now, it populates the dropdown with all schools at first, even if the school list is 100 schools. I need the last item in the list (a button to add a school) to be visible without needing to scroll down to see it. Limiting it to displaying 4 schools at any time should be good.

Comment: you can simply use `slice()` for that purpose I would say.

Comment: Could you show me how? I'm adding `.pipe(slice())` after the last `.pipe(take1)` but it's not showing up.

Comment: Here, see the `performFilter()` function: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jd2dsu-cgvphc?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother again - I noticed the list isn't listening for updates of docs added to the `Schools` collection. The user needs to manually refresh the page to show the updated list of schools. Could you add in a listener?